# Invade the Pyramid if you Dare

Tags: cipher

Before you lies a pyramid, with a giant statue blocking the entrance.

```
            ab            
           abcd     I     
    D     abcdHf          
         abOdefgh         
        abcdSfghij     N  
       abcdefghijkl       
      abcdefgEijklmn      
     abcdKfghijklmnop     
    abcdefghijklmnopqr    
   abcdefghijklmnopqrst   
  FbcTefghijklmnopqrstCv  
 aJcdefghijklmnBpqrRtPvwx 
abcdLfghijklmMopqQstuGwxAz
```

The statue projects the above image onto the ground in front of your feet, it's obviously something you'll need to know to enter the pyramid! Maybe decrypting it will allow you to enter! What did that creepy statue try to tell you?

EDIT: An old light flickered revealing the truth thanks to a passing spirit named "Bewilderer", how bewildering.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The creepy statue told me:

> "you have been cursed"

Method:

> The letters A-T (uppercase) each appear once.  Place the letters that they replace in the pyramid in order.  D, I, and N are spaces.
>
> ```
>  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
>  you have been cursed
> ```

Comment: Well, I guess it's my fault; I thought it'd help us get treasure :(. Unfortunate.